# Why does Wicket changes the id of the html elements?

Tags: html, wicket, identifier

If I write

```
<form wicket:id="form" id="form>
```

or even

```
<form wicket:id="form>...
```

Then the rendered HTML shows the id 'form' appended with different numbers whenever the page is refreshed e.g.

```
   <form id="form7"....
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior of the Wicket framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the behavior you want in most cases when using wicket. The dynamic id is meant to prevent id collisions when Ajax behaviors are added to components or added to ajax responses for refreshing. For any of these situations, you really need both the client response and the server side state to be in cahoots.  If there are external js resources you need the id of a component for dom lookup, then I would suggest adding a custom wicket component behavior that would then generate the js call to a function passing in the generated id.

I realize what I'm going to describe leads you more into the forest of Wicket. But I have been more than happy with the ajaxy stuff that Wicket opens up for you out of the box.

Comment: is it a Wicket norm to write even Javascript in the Java files?

Comment: Like everything else unfortunately, it depends. There are examples for libraries of JS (wicket-ajax.js for example) and generated JS from within java. The Wicket source code should have examples of both. Ultimately just about any of the standard ajax behaviors at some point will include a standard header contributor to include the wicket-ajax.js file. Check out some of the ajax components for seeing generated JS many will have a get generated js method or something to attach to the component that it is added to.

Comment: @Monis: I prefer putting the *minimal* amount of JS in the Java code, typically just a call to a function in separate a .js file. [One example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8848464/56285).

Answer (score 21):

We set markup ids by hand extensively on our project to ease automatic testing with Selenium testing framework. It definitely works.

```
Component.setOutputMarkupId(true); // write id attribute of element to html
Component.setMarkupId("someid"); // id attribute of element is "someid"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is Wicket desing feature. You can use class for linking styles and components.

```
<form wicket:id="form" id="form>
```

Also you can to try (I never did it) [setMarkupId](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setMarkupId%28java.lang.String%29) . I'm not sure that it good way.

Comment: setMarkupId is the way how to do that see my answer below

Comment: oh, sorry. I misread it as setOutputMarkupId(true). Apologies @leonidv. and thanks @Michal

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I worked with Wicket, but I remember that when wicket uses ajax elements, its `id`s are auto-generated (the `id` of the tag, not the `wicket:id`). You can control the id of the tag when not using and ajax element. In your case, since there is no code, I would guess that you will have to change any `AjaxButton` or `Ajax*` from your form.

Comment: The problems I am facing with these changing ids are on the client-side stuff, like my css cannot use these ids to map the styles, I cannot write javascript that plays with the element ids.

Comment: @Monis Iqbal You're supposed to use Wicket's Ajax hooks etc. directly.

Comment: meaning that I cannot write custom javascript? Isn't this violation of SOC that Wicket supports? because javascript is supposed to be client-side.

Comment: @MonisIqbal You use facilities such as `target.appendJavaScript(..)` among others

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write custom JavaScript... you just need to implement it according to the 'Wicket way'. You can decorate components, Ajax calls etc. with custom JavaScript, then it all plays nicely.